# Resources within dependencies not added to the classpath

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, resources, dependencies

I am new to IntelliJ and I want to setup a project as follows:
The product I wanna work on is included as a compile dependency within a gradle build file. It has a lot of transitive dependencies.

The product includes an Jetty Application Server which I wanna start up with a run configuration.
If I try to run it I am facing a problem, that the Application Server won't startup because it doesn't find resource files included in the dependencies. Those files are specific for this product and have a custom file format. If I have a look into those dependencies in the "Project Explorer" I can find those files but it seems like they aren't added to the classpath correctly.

Do you know a way to solve this issue?

**EDIT: Added console ouput**

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:53443,suspend=y,server=n -javaagent:C:\Users\xyzhe\.IntelliJIdea14\system\groovyHotSwap\gragent.jar -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.1\lib\util.jar" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper C:\Users\xyzhe\AppData\Local\Temp\classpath1.tmp com.xyz.xyz.server.ApplicationServer
```

[...]

```
DEBUG    2| Java classpath (java.class.path): 
    C:\Workspaces\idea\test\build\resources\main
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\charsets.jar
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\deploy.jar
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\javaws.jar
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\jce.jar
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\jfr.jar
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\jfxrt.jar
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\jsse.jar
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\management-agent.jar
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\plugin.jar
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\resources.jar
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\rt.jar
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar
    D:\gradle-repository\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.xyz.customersolution.gradle.templates\database-jar-fix\1.0.2-SNAPSHOT\130dddff1f42c974ae3596d930650f0625bb6ce0\database-jar-fix-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
    D:\gradle-repository\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.eclipse.jetty.orbit\org.eclipse.jdt.core\3.8.2.v20130121\ebb04771ae21dec8682e4153e97404d9933a9c13\org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.8.2.v20130121.jar
    D:\gradle-repository\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.xyz.xyz\standardreports\5.4.0\a7cb55b52375485e9e7a50f1178f8422c051c060\standardreports-5.4.0.jar
    D:\gradle-repository\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.xyz.xyz\xyz\5.4.0\ca28dfa960714909e2a8f90bcc76f6a0b6b49ca8\xyz-5.4.0.jar
    D:\gradle-repository\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.wicket\wicket-core\6.11.0\8053fa17c6763d3cab3c9f29b15b2249fd3965b6\wicket-core-6.11.0.jar
    D:\gradle-repository\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.xyz.xyz\xml-form-generator\5.4.0\1fdac3321d5cd3d924ff5b1072d7e238a89f86d5\xml-form-generator-5.4.0.jar
    D:\gradle-repository\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.xyz.xyz\as\5.4.0\91c7fd68d3d54ab6543c08bb00328bb6c2ee0b4d\as-5.4.0.jar
    D:\gradle-repository\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.xyz.xyz\mangocards\5.4.0\9cf3d615525d181c3f9664ebf7aaf621ad50b744\mangocards-5.4.0.jar
    D:\gradle-repository\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.xyz.xyz\persistence\5.4.0\3ab80e15a1cf5b07be5ec103229289caf1658e51\persistence-5.4.0.jar
    D:\gradle-repository\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.xyz.xyz\processpages\5.4.0\1969ebd46e33a60efcb7d0eadc2716d5a576ba56\processpages-5.4.0.jar
    D:\gradle-repository\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.xyz.xyz\scheduling\5.4.0\59a3adcc87eefc15f2b09908aa084bbabc87618c\scheduling-5.4.0.jar
    D:\gradle-repository\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.xyz.xyz\xyz-permissions\5.4.0\c2dfc971d1ca566115a1c2909cf2dc375d768856\xyz-permissions-5.4.0.jar
    D:\gradle-repository\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.xyz.xyz\import\5.4.0\e897764ebe7c789cf5e96b776b27c303b2660716\import-5.4.0.jar
    D:\gradle-repository\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.xyz.xyz\cti\5.4.0\632320b61aaaf11dc5c01a844e4497ec4a2a788b\cti-5.4.0.jar
    D:\gradle-repository\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.xyz.xyz\mobile\5.4.0\e1d004b497714dab8ccd05ac4b47652fe5073c09\mobile-5.4.0.jar
    D:\gradle-repository\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.xyz.utils.logging\logging-logback\1.4\2686750910ad01a75c9a0944fb3a84cd86f5d9d\logging-logback-1.4.jar
    D:\gradle-repository\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.xyz.utils.webauth\web-authentication\0.9\ea71e4ce1d4f7a37515af2b07d515adb33384173\web-authentication-0.9.jar
    D:\gradle-repository\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.xyz.xyz\mangodata\5.4.0\1b657225530e22f3c28603b3710360b37de23b94\mangodata-5.4.0.jar
    D:\gradle-repository\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.xyz.xyz\wm-implementation\5.4.0\c38dbe4fcfecc4074b3a80f965d6415201fc3db4\wm-implementation-5.4.0.jar
    D:\gradle-repository\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.xyz.xyz\planboard-gui\5.4.0\4e47e003fa9b7da7c14d009345bfcd9c4cae8dac\planboard-gui-5.4.0.jar
    D:\gradle-repository\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.xyz.xyz\importwizard\5.4.0\86452ecf87035ab51a2fb06ec3f14bcffce9e9d2\importwizard-5.4.0.jar
    D:\gradle-repository\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\83cd2cd674a217ade95a4bb83a8a14f351f48bd0\antlr-2.7.7.jar
    D:\gradle-repository\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.novel.ecb\ecb\1.4\b71404cc296e6d4f4670ee78366a0b95181cb0ee\ecb-1.4.jar
    D:\gradle-repository\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.novel.ecb\ecbldap\1.4\6897a1d220d5f7e74b49246f9931707ce802a79b\ecbldap-1.4.jar
[...]
INFO     2| Loading BZR lists "bzrlist_admin.bzrs"...                                                                                               | com.xyz.bzr.support.ParsedDefinitionSetHelper.createFromIntermediateResources(ParsedDefinitionSetHelper.java:88)
WARN     2| No BZR lists named "bzrlist_admin.bzrs"                                                                                                 | com.xyz.bzr.support.ParsedDefinitionSetHelper.createFromIntermediateResources(ParsedDefinitionSetHelper.java:113)
INFO     2| Resolving...                                                                                                                            | com.xyz.bzr.resolver.DefinitionResolver.resolveInternally(DefinitionResolver.java:172)
INFO     2| Loading BZR lists "corebzrlist.bzrs"...                                                                                                 | com.xyz.bzr.support.ParsedDefinitionSetHelper.createFromIntermediateResources(ParsedDefinitionSetHelper.java:88)
WARN     2| No BZR lists named "corebzrlist.bzrs"                                                                                                   | com.xyz.bzr.support.ParsedDefinitionSetHelper.createFromIntermediateResources(ParsedDefinitionSetHelper.java:113)
INFO     2| Loading BZR lists "bzrlist.bzrs"...                                                                                                     | com.xyz.bzr.support.ParsedDefinitionSetHelper.createFromIntermediateResources(ParsedDefinitionSetHelper.java:88)
WARN     2| No BZR lists named "bzrlist.bzrs"                                                                                                       | com.xyz.bzr.support.ParsedDefinitionSetHelper.createFromIntermediateResources(ParsedDefinitionSetHelper.java:113)
INFO     2| Resolving...                                                                                                                            | com.xyz.bzr.resolver.DefinitionResolver.resolveInternally(DefinitionResolver.java:172)
INFO     2| No file 'management.users' present
```

**EDIT: Correct Eclipse output**

```
INFO     2| Loading BZR lists "corebzrlist.bzrs"      com.xyz.bzr.support.ParsedDefinitionSetHelper.createFromIntermediateResources(ParsedDefinitionSetHelper.java:78)
INFO     2| - Loading BZRs from "file:/D:/gradle-repository/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.xyz.tas/xyz-core-bzr/5.6.0-beta5-20150326-1730/bf9bd5caf5977f7506c66f43f586b2eead4c3a55/xyz-core-bzr-5.6.0-beta5-20150326-1730.jar!/corebzrlist.bzrs"...     | com.xyz.bzr.support.ParsedDefinitionSetHelper.createFromIntermediateResources(ParsedDefinitionSetHelper.java:85)
```

**EDIT: Added image of project explorer**

[Project Explorer](http://i62.tinypic.com/2m31snp.jpg)

Comment: Gradle only takes care for loading the files so they are around for the compilation within the IDE. How do you launch the project in the application server? Is the application server aware for the dependencies?

Comment: I launch the ApplicationServer with a run configuration within the IDE. I define the Main class: "com.test.ApplicationServer" and define some VM options.
The Application Server is aware of the dependencies because when I startup the server the classpath is printed out in the console and every dependency is listed there.
I used eclipse before and there the launch configuration works.

Comment: They are listed in the launch command line with the correct path but they are still not present in the classpath?

Comment: The class files are present but not the config resource files within the jars.

Comment: You did notice that the jar file the bzrs resource is load from is not part of the classpath you wrote in the upper section, right? Why is it missing? Is the reference to this file missing in gradle or something?

Comment: The bzrs are in the mangocards-5.4.0.jar file and this jar ist loaded within the classpath as you can see above.
Edit: Sorry except for the "corebzrlist.bzrs" this one is loaded in a different jar but it is also on the classpath I just didn't copy the whole classpath.

Comment: According to the eclipse output the bzr files are in: `xyz-core-bzr-5.6.0-beta5-20150326-1730.jar` And that file is missing.

Comment: Sorry except for the "corebzrlist.bzrs" this one is loaded in a different jar but it is also on the classpath I just didn't copy the whole classpath.

Comment: Is it really in the jar file? If the file is missing it would be about the only explanation I can think of. Or is the thing that searches for the bzrs files limited *where* it searches for the file? Or is it just scanning the entire classpath?

Comment: I added a snapshot from my External Libraries Section within the IntelliJ Project. I can only post a link to the image because have not enought reputation to post an image

Comment: That looks okay. Now the question stands how the loading of that file in the source code happens. Maybe something is off there.

Comment: ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResources("corebzrlist.bzrs");
this way the bzr file is called.

In eclipse this it works.

Comment: I always avoid the SystemClassLoader. You sure you need that one? Try it with `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` There is a chance that the system class loader sees a different classpath.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I rewrite the code to use the Thread contextclassloader and now it works!!! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution in that case was that the wrong class loader was used.

The instance of the classloader returned by `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()` was unable to fetch the required resources. Apparently this classloader is working with the wrong classpath.

In most cases it is the better idea to use the classloader of the current execution context that is returned by `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()`